# summing cells where header is in a list

Tags: excel-formula

I frequently run into the following situation:

- I have a table in excel where rows are cases and columns are items
  (eg. i_01 - i_88).
- For each case (row) I need to add certain items to create scale
  values for that case (eg. s_01=Sum(i_02,i_23,i_76...),
  s_02=Sum(i_05,i_11,i_34...), and so on).

How can I do this by specifying a range where the item headers for a given scale are?

Something along these lines:

> =SUMIF(value_range, item_header_range, item_header_subset_range)

I know this is what databases are for but I would like to have a solution in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend a lot on how you laid out your data, but if it was something like the screenshot you could use an array formula to add only the items in columns where the column name matched the list of items in rows 2-4 of S1 and S2:

[image]

Here's the formula in plain text:-

=SUM($A5:$D5*NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$D$1,E$2:E$4,0))))